# Vuejs Google place autocomplete with typescript & vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
  <b-form-textarea
    :id="id"
    ref="autocomplete"
    v-model="autocompleteText"
    rows="3"
    max-rows="6"
    type="text"
    :class="classname"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    @focus="onFocus()"
    @blur="onBlur()"
    @change="onChange"
    @keypress="onKeyPress"
    @keyup="onKeyUp"
  />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({
      name: 'AddressInput'
    })
export default class extends Vue {
  @Watch('autocompleteText')
  private autocompleteTextChange(newVal:any, oldVal:any) {
    this.$emit('inputChange', { newVal, oldVal }, this.id);
  }

  @Watch('country')
  private countryChange(newVal:any, oldVal:any) {
    this.autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
      country: this.country === null ? [] : this.country
    });
  }

  mounted() {
    const options:any = {};
    if (this.types) {
      options.types = [this.types];
    }

    if (this.country) {
      options.componentRestrictions = {
        country: this.country
      };
    }

    this.autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById(this.id),
        options
    );

    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.onPlaceChanged);
  }

  private onPlaceChanged() {
    let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      this.$emit('no-results-found', place, this.id);
      return;
    }

    if (place.address_components !== undefined) {
      this.$emit('placechanged', this.formatResult(place), place, this.id);

      this.autocompleteText = (document.getElementById(this.id) as HTMLInputElement).value;
      this.onChange()
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

I'm trying to create a google place autocomplete component using Vuejs & typescript & vue-property-decorator. Autocomplete place suggestions are coming. But I'm getting an error "InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement". I tried with $refs also but same error is coming.

Please ask me if you have any doubt I will try to explain.

What I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

[image: Image error response]

[image: Render component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says "not an instance of HTMLInputElement".

Use an input element instead of the textarea element

`<input type="text />`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with <input type="text /> it's working. Is it possible I can use textarea element.